# JBOSS_HOME spring resource mapping

Tags: spring, jboss

Hi guys I can't properly map my JBOSS_HOME location for example I have something like this:

```
<mvc:resources order="-10" location="file:/C:/Serwery/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/" mapping="/test/**" />
```

But this is absolute path I want to make something like this:

```
<mvc:resources order="-10" location="file:/$JBOSS_HOME/" mapping="/test/**" />
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

to your xml configuration where you have the `<mvc:resources />` and use it like this (notice how the env variable is handled - `${JBOSS_HOME}`):

```
<mvc:resources order="-10" location="file:/${JBOSS_HOME}/" mapping="/test/**" />
```